# NSFetchedResultsController with non unique section name

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am initialising `NSFetchedResultsController` with following code

```
self.fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(
            fetchRequest: request,
            managedObjectContext: context,
            sectionNameKeyPath: "article.name",cacheName: nil
        )
```

Here articles can have same name.So `article.name` `sectionNameKeyPath` is non unique.In this case `fetchedResultsController` will have only single section.

How can I handle multiple section with same section name?

Comment: then, what is the need for showing them as sections?, why don't you just show them as rows?

Comment: @raki see I have 5 components ( entity )  in which 2 are related to Article A and rest related to Article B .So my section names will be Article A,Article B.But If I am changing name of both article to X then I will one section thats the problem !

Comment: can you show the data model structure?

Comment: You should use unique id of article as sectionNameKeyPath

Comment: @jiama What if the section names are non unique.In my case user can change the name, so there is possibility of having two sections with same name.

Comment: @UIBittu Maybe you need add unique id for article

Comment: @jiama I have unique id for article but I need to display the article name as section title.If I am using the NSFetchedResultsController ,how can I achieve that ?

Comment: @UIBittu If they are 5 article, you want to display them in 5 sections without grouping them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sectionKeyPath return a UUID for the section (article.articleId or the like).  Then when you display the title for the header in section don't display the named returned from the fetchedResultsController (`self.fetchedResultsController.sections[section].name`), rather get the first object in the section and figure out what you really want to display based on that (`self.fetchedResultsController.sections[section].objects.firstObject.article.name`).